# How to avoid creating a wrapping element when referencing an XML type in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-xml

I'm fooling around with `FOR XML` in SQL Server 2008 to see if it would be a better fit for building web service response's rather than relying on Hibernate & HQL to map DTO's (or mapping them manually from flat result sets).

I created a fictive example where persons may have children and a collection of phone numbers.

I'm facing a situation where `SELECT name FROM personCte` will procude an unwanted wrapping `<name>` element, resulting in `<name><name first="test" last="test"/></name>`.

I can get rid of the extra wrapping element by doing the following, but I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate way of doing it?

```
SELECT (select name)
FROM personCte
```

One problem with that solution is that it cannot be used in CTE's, since all CTE columns must be named.

I would also like to know if there are better ways to unflatten multiple properties into a single element (e.g firstName and lastName into name) than doing a subquery?

Here's the sample code I'm using:

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    firstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    parentId int NULL
);

DECLARE @PersonPhoneNumber TABLE (
    personId int NOT NULL,
    number char(12) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO @Person (firstName, lastName, parentId)
VALUES 
    ('Person', 'A', NULL),
    ('Person', 'B', 1),
    ('Person', 'C', 2);

INSERT INTO @PersonPhoneNumber
VALUES
    (1, '888-888-8888'),
    (1, '999-999-9999'),
    (3, '333-333-3333');



;WITH personCte AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        (
            SELECT firstName AS [@first], lastName AS [@last]
            FROM @Person
            WHERE id = person.id
            FOR XML PATH('name'), TYPE
        ) AS name,
        (
            SELECT number
            FROM @PersonPhoneNumber
            WHERE personId = person.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS phoneNumbers,
        parentId
    FROM @Person person
)
SELECT 
        id, 
        (SELECT name), /* Used to avoid unwanted wrapping name element */
        phoneNumbers, 
        parentId,
        (
            SELECT id, (SELECT name), phoneNumbers, parentId
            FROM personCte person
            WHERE parentId = p.id
            FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
        ) AS children
    FROM personCte p
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('persons'), TYPE
```

Which correctly produces:

```
<persons>
  <person id="1">
    <name first="Person" last="A" />
    <phoneNumbers>
      <number>888-888-8888</number>
      <number>999-999-9999</number>
    </phoneNumbers>
    <children>
      <person id="2" parentId="1">
        <name first="Person" last="B" />
      </person>
    </children>
  </person>
  <person id="2" parentId="1">
    <name first="Person" last="B" />
    <children>
      <person id="3" parentId="2">
        <name first="Person" last="C" />
        <phoneNumbers>
          <number>333-333-3333</number>
        </phoneNumbers>
      </person>
    </children>
  </person>
  <person id="3" parentId="2">
    <name first="Person" last="C" />
    <phoneNumbers>
      <number>333-333-3333</number>
    </phoneNumbers>
  </person>
</persons>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `query()` XML method to exclude unwanted nesting:

```
select p.id, p.name.query('.')
FROM personCte p
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('persons'), TYPE;
```

EDIT: What you need is to rewrite everything with `PATH()` syntax. In this case, you would not need any methods, and also you will be able to specify nested nodes, which doesn't work with `AUTO`. So, your full query will look like this:

```
;WITH personCte AS (
    SELECT id, parentId, firstName, lastName, (
        SELECT number
        FROM @PersonPhoneNumber
        WHERE personId = person.id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS phoneNumbers
    FROM @Person person
)
SELECT 
    p.id as [@id],
    p.parentId as [@parentid],
    p.firstName AS [name/@first],
    p.lastName AS [name/@last],
    p.phoneNumbers,
    (
        SELECT id as [@id], parentId as [@parentid],
            person.firstName AS [name/@first],
            person.lastName AS [name/@last],
            phoneNumbers
        FROM personCte person
        WHERE parentId = p.id
        FOR XML path('person'), TYPE
    ) AS children
FROM personCte p
FOR XML path('person'), ROOT('persons'), TYPE;
```

Comment: Is `query` an expensive call in terms of performance? By unflattening I mean that in the database, I have a firstName and a lastName column, but in the actual XML I want a `<name first="..." last="..."/>` element. I'm currently using a nested query to achieve this, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: Performance of `query()` will be peanuts compared with `for xml auto`. You really should get rid of this monster and rewrite everything with `path()` syntax.

Comment: Also, with `path()` you can determine more complex structure, sometimes without resorting to additional subqueries. In this case, it will be something like:`select p.id as [@Id], p.parentId as [@ParentId], p.firstName as [Name/@First], p.lastName as [Name/@Last]
from @Person p
for xml path('Person'), type, root('Persons');`

Comment: Great! I was sure there was a better alternative... I'll give it a try tomorrow morning at work at award the answer if it works properly ;) Thanks!